# SQL order by for nodes

Tags: sql

Everytime I try to put some XML data into my table it's ordering it by the description (please see below). I only want the table to maintain the order of the data as it comes in but it won't - why is this?

Here is my SQL:

```
declare cur1 cursor local fast_forward for

    select
        P.DescriptionId, N.Description
    from (
        select
            T.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Description
        from @TheRole.nodes('/descriptions/description') as T(C)

    ) as N
        left outer join PositionsDescriptions as P on P.Description = N.Description
```

Where I'm inputting something like this:

```
@TheRole = '<descriptions><description>test1</description><description>cd</description><description>ab</description></descriptions>'
```

But the data stored is in alphabetical order - i.e. ab, cd, test1 and NOT test1, cd, ab as I inputted it.

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using? Also, I don't see an `insert` statement anywere.

Comment: The insert comes at the end:  insert INTO Positions_Descriptions(PositionId, SectionId, DescriptionId, OrderNumber)
  VALUES (@PositionId, 2, @DescriptionId, @OrderNumber)

Comment: But by this point the xml is already in the wrong order - it's something to do with the cursor/ select stuff at the top

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include (1) the above insert (2) the sql dialect you are using (a tag is also highly recommended) and (3) the way you reached the conclusion about the stored order.

Comment: Also, does `Positions_Descriptions` have any _clustered_ index? If yes, on what column?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: In the relational model a relation is an unordered collection. Order only matters when you retrieve information and explicitly order it with an `ORDER BY` statement.